# How do I write code in order to generate random numbers in a way that a random number can only be printed once every 5 times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written code in python in order to generate random numbers between 110-115, 19 times. The code works however I would like to add code that states that the same random numbers cannot be printed out next to each other, they can only be printed out after the other 5 numbers have been used. for example:

[112, 113, 115, 110, 111, 114, 112, 113, 115, 110, 111, 114...]

until 19 values have been printed.

I have the following code:

```
randomlist = []

for i in range(19):
    
    n = random.randint(110,115)
    randomlist.append(n)

print(*randomlist, sep = "\n")
```

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to think about the logic of the problem. In particular: suppose that the first six values we get are `112, 113, 115, 110, 111, 114`, as in your example. Can the next value be **anything else besides** `112`? Why or why not? How about the next value? It will be forced to be `113`, correct? Therefore, can you think of a simpler way to describe the desired output? Is there actually a point in using randomness, after the first six elements have been chosen?

Comment: Next: can you think of another word to describe what is done, in order to set the order of those six elements? (It has seven letters, starts with `s`, and ends with `e`). Do you see such a method [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, to generate 19 nos where no repetition in 5 consecutive nos.

```
import random
randomlist = []
while len(randomlist) < 19:
    n = random.randint(110,115)
    if n not in randomlist[-5:]:
        randomlist.append(n)
    else:
        continue
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: It works thanks, however could you please explain what the [-5] in randomlist[-5:] does

Comment: Glad to help... Sure @Wasmot So, basically just [-5:] will give us the last 5 items from the list.. & in the if condition simply checking if newly created random number is in those last 5 nos, if so then generate random number again else append to the list...

Answer (score -1):

Try this below code , it will solve your problem.

```
import random
randomlist = []
i = 0
number_of_values = 19

while len(randomlist) < number_of_values:
    n = random.randint(110,115)
    if n not in randomlist[-5:]:
        randomlist.append(n)
print(randomlist, sep = "\n")
```